# Blazor modifying CaptureUnmatchedValues existing attribute is not re-rendered

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Blazor WebAssembly on .NET 5.

In a component, I am capturing the additional attributes that the user might add.

```
[Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
public Dictionary<string, object> AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }
```

```
<li @onclick="TabSelected" @attributes="AdditionalAttributes">
@ChildContent
</li>
```

At `TabSelected` event, I am checking if CSS `class` is added and if not I add it and give it a value `active` and if it is added, I just append `active` to the existing dictionary of key `class`. I am also calling `StateHasChanged()` after.

`AdditionalAttributes` is manipulated in the right way.

However, if `class` doesn't exist and I have added it and gave it a value, then it is re-rendered as expected. But if `class` already exists and I have just appended  `active`, this is not re-rendered!

**How can I force re-rendering on a modified value?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract class attribute from the AdditionalAttributes collection and set it directly to the component. This should work correctly.

However, if you want to force full re-rendering, You can use @key attribute to suppress Blazor's rendering optimizations:

```
<li @onclick="TabSelected" @key="key" @attributes="AdditionalAttributes">
@ChildContent
</li>
@code {
    int key = 0;
    void TabSelected {
         //do what you need
         key++;
    }
}
```

Be aware that this may affect performance. more information here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-key-to-control-the-preservation-of-elements-and-components

Explanation

If something changes, like the value of a parameter, Blazor uses an algorithm to calculate the difference between the current view and the upcoming view. Only the difference is then submitted to manipulate the DOM. The @key directive is used to give this algorithm a hint, what element should preserve. If the key doesn't change, there is no need for rerendering.

This solution plays if the inversion of the tool. If we want a component to be rerendered regardless of the actual content, we need to change the key.

In your example, a rerendering should occur every time the tab is selected. It is easy enough to choose a counter and increase it every time the event is handled. Other possible methods like new Guid or random numbers, are also possible.

Comment: Hi Artur. I can extract it and I can change it but if `class` is already supplied and I try to modify it, my modifications will not be rendered. So, this is not answering my specific question. Re-rendering everything is my last resort, I want to see why my modified class is not re-rendered like any other attribute

Comment: I have created simple project from standard template with the code above. You can find it here https://github.com/ArturGogiyan/RuntimeAttributeChanging. As I see, the "class" attribute changes every time the li tag clicked. Сan you reproduce the behavior you described with this example?

Comment: Artur, the problem turned out to be that I need to trigger the `StateHasChanged()` on the inner component. Thank you for your help.